# How can I convert XML to Java object if I don't know the Java object in advance?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xstream

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("test.xml"); // load your XML file  
XStream xstream = new XStream(); // init XStream  
// Define root alias so XStream knows which element and which class are equivalent.
xstream.alias("test", Test.class);   
Test test = (Test) xstream.fromXML(fileReader);
```

Note: The above process is if I know the class in advance, but if I don't know the about test.class, then how can it be converted into a Java class?

Comment: If you don't know the Test.class, your Java code simply won't compile. I think, XStream makes sense when you do know both your XML and your Java class and just need a quick way to convert one instance into another. If the structure of your XML is not known in advance, you probably need some other API (e.g. DOM) to deal with it and, above all, to have some clear idea what you are going to do with such a generic XML.

Answer (score 0):

Data binding technologies such as JAXB map an XML schema to an set of classes in an object oriented language such as Java; they only work if the XML schema is stable and the mapping to Java classes is stable and known in advance.

When you're dealing with XML instances whose structure isn't known in advance, or whose structure has many variants and versions, then data binding technologies aren't appropriate. For these you need a more generic approach, for example use of DOM-like APIs (XOM and JDOM2 are probably the best), or non-schema-aware XSLT or XQuery.

Comment: can u give me an example with XSLT or XQuery

Comment: I've no idea what you want to achieve, so I don't know what you want the example to do.

Comment: like i have only an xml file and if i don't have java class corresponding xml thats why i want to create an java class on the basis of xml schema . using java code or any other way

Comment: "Creating a Java class" is not what you want to achieve, it's what you perceive as being a means to an end. Probably the best way to achieve your goals does not involve creating a Java class, that's why I was asking about your goals.

Comment: actually i am requesting some service as a client . that service response in xml after getting that xml string i need to convert that string into java object so that every time my service will hit that service i will get that xml response into java object.

Comment: Most people do this by reading the data into a DOM tree. I'm not saying that's the best way, because I don't know what your underlying requirements are, but you seem to be only considering one design approach, and it's not the best one in the circumstances.

Comment: is any API which one i can use and read xml element like DOM api ask for conversion type class and convert xml into that class but i will create new class as per xml structure .

Comment: You can't create a Java class for a particular XML structure until you know what the structure is. If you don't know the structure until run-time, then you would need to create a Java class at run-time which is very hard work and not very useful. Just use DOM in the ordinary way like everyone else does.

Comment: Actually i am using this now but i am not much familiar with this if you familiar let me know if you don't mind

File file = new File("D:/Rajesh_works/certificate/CZU-KHN1800037.xml");
   DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
   System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
   if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {}